# C: char logical operator not working

Tags: c, io, logical-operators

Using the code

```
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &num1);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%c", &op);
    sscanf(argv[3], "%d", &num2);

        if ((op != '-')||(op != '*')||(op != '/')||(op != '+'))
    {
        puts("Error:");
        printf("'%c' is not a valid operator", op);
        return 0;
    }
```

Compiles fine.

However, does not work for any input. For instance when the input is 4 + 7

Console prints:

> Error:
>
> '+' is not a valid operator

Edit: without this error checking code, the rest of the programme operates correctly, including a switch statement based on op!

Comment: You need to replace your `||` with `&&`.

Comment: _char logical operator not working_ is quite wrong, unless you're using a broken compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makes sense, since your condition is always true.

```
 (op != '-')||(op != '*')||(op != '/')||(op != '+')
```

or even

```
 (op != '-')||(op != '*')
```

will always evaluate to `true`.

You're basically saying "If `op` is not `-` **OR** `op` is not `*`... do whatever".

You probably meant to use `&&` instead.

Comment: if not equal to Z: then do X, else: do Y. It is equal to Z, but does X... ?

Comment: Stupid me. I think I was thinking of exclusive or. :/

Answer (score 3):

You have a logic problem. You should change the OR (||) operator with AND (&&)

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
   if ((op != '-')&&(op != '*')&&(op != '/')&&(op != '+'))
```